# What is the optimised way to fetch all items and related name, email from parent table using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

We have a table of order consisting of order IDs. what is considered 'best practice' in terms of fetching all item data with their order?

```
Order table:
--------

| id   | name   | email           | phone     | event_id |
|----  |------  | -----           |-----      | -----    |
| 1    | Anish  | anish@gmail.com | 8233472332| 1765     |
| 2    | ABC    | abc@gmail.com   | 784472332 | 1765     |
| 3    | XYZ    | xyz@gmail.com   | 646322332 | 1525     |
```

items table:

```
| id   | order_id | category   |  qty | price |
|----  |------    | -----      |----- | ----- |
| 1    | 1        | person 1   | 2    | 299   |
| 2    | 1        | person 2   | 1    | 399   |
| 3    | 2        | person 1   | 1    | 299   |
```

I want to fetch all items and their order name, email, phone in a single query.

Expected result

```
| name     | email             | category   |  qty | price |
|----      |------             | -----------|----- | ----- |
|  Anish   | anish@gmail.com   | person 1   | 2    | 299   |
| Anish    | anish@gmail.com.  | person 2   | 1    | 399   |
| ABC      | abc@gmail.com     | person 1   | 1    | 299   |
```

**One to many relations**
Orders -> items (It has multiple rows related to a single order)

I want to display all items for an event (example: event id - 1765) along with name, email, and phone. Please tell me the optimized mysql query. I am using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: Are you really asking for optimisations (optimise what? execution time? memory usage? what data size?) or just a way to get that data?

Comment: What have you tried? We love to help people but SO isn't a free dev service. And why such an old version of Laravel?

Comment: The client is using an old version of Laravel and for now, they just want to enhance a few features. Don't want to upgrade the version. It takes longer time to fetch data. Want to optimise the execution

Answer (score 1):

You can get that result by using a simple inner join between your two tables:

```
SELECT
  `order`.`name`,
  `order`.`email`,
  `items`.`category`,
  `items`.`qty`,
  `items`.`price`
FROM `order`
INNER JOIN `items` ON
  `order`.`id` = `items`.`order_id`
```